# regex substring/replacement in oracle and sql server

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, oracle, hibernate

I'm tring to search only the alphanumeric part of a String in the database.

```
String stringToSearch= originalString.replaceAll("[^\\p{IsAlphabetic}^\\p{IsDigit}]", "")
```

However oracle and sql server both use different functions to replace regex. And I'm writing code that might work on an SQL Server or an Oracle stack depending on the client.

i'm trying to have a clause like this that works for both servers :

```
query.addClause("REGEXP_SUBSTR('column1','[[:alphanum:]]') = ?", stringToSearch);
```

Thought about doing a `REPLACE` for each non alphanumeric character but you can imagine the speed of the query ...

Is there any function that I'm not aware of?

Note that, there could be two solutions : substring on the alphanumerical characters or replacing the non alphanumerical ones with "".

Comment: Actually nested replace is super fast. However, I would not recommend it for this type of thing because there are way too many characters that are not a number. I don't know of a generic way that works in both DBMSs that is also going to perform well. This type of thing would be a good argument for getting the data out of the code and into the database. That way you can leverage the power of each database and your application is not so tightly coupled to the data.

Comment: Doing it the other way around can be fixed with nested substrings of [a-zA-Z0-9] but isn't it going to be slow?

Comment: can you explain "This type of thing would be a good argument for getting the data out of the code and into the database." please? you meant out of the database into the code?

Comment: No I would never suggest moving data retrieval into the code. What you posted looks like creating sql in managed code and you want a generic query for more than 1 DBMS. My suggestion is to move the data retrieval to the database. Stored proc or whatever. That way you can customize the sql to fit the DBMS you are using.